# Can I replace battery of My HP Pavilion DV6 2020e notebook to work for 3-5 hours?

Tags: laptop, battery-life, hp-pavilion

I bought **HP Pavilion DV6 2020e** notebook from 6 months and i found that its battery last for max 70 minutes and i contact hp support and they told me that this model can last for max 90 minute according to its 6 cell battery :(

Can any know if this model battery can be replaced by one that can last for 3-4 hours ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** HP Document: [How to Improve the Performance of the Battery](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01297640&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=4064538)
**2)** If that is not enough buy an [Extended-Life Battery](http://www.shopping.hp.com/product/computer/categories/notebook_batteries/1/accessories/KS526AA) 
     – The 12 cell should give you around 4-5 hours battery life.

Comment: No Problem ... Easy One